# Webcomponent Polyfill Element Cache: Reset/Empty?

Tags: javascript, web-component, polyfills

I'm currently using FireFox + the Webcomponent Polyfill. The Webcomponent changes as AJAX calls provide different data sets (Essentially a search form that provides links to related topics).  However, I am trying to write some JavaScript that will query the AJAX results as they are displayed in the ShadowDOM.

My problem is that when I run my query, if the old data set is larger than the new results, I get my new results + the remaining length of elements from the old search.

For example (nodelist elements simplified for point of illustration):

```
Search1: "Teenage Mutant Ninja Turtles"
Resulting NodeList: ['Teenage', 'Mutant', 'Ninja', 'Turtles']
```

Follow that up with another search...

```
Search2: "Inspector Gadget"
Resulting NodeList: ['Inspector', 'Gadget', 'Ninja', 'Turtles']

Search3: "Warner Brother's Tiny Toon Adventures"
Resulting NodeList: ['Warner', 'Brother\'s', 'Tiny', 'Toon', 'Adventures']

Search4: "Freakazoid"
Resulting NodeList: ['Freakazoid', 'Brother\'s', 'Tiny', 'Toon', 'Adventures']
```

My query code looks like:

```
var nodes = document.querySelector('search-component').shadowRoot.querySelectorAll('div.result');
```

Is there a way to query the polyfilled webcomponent nodelist and get only the DOM elements that exist in that current moment in time (disregarding the previous elements that may have existed)?

Comment: You should provide your code

Comment: Are you saying that `shadowRoot.querySelectorAll` is returning elements that are no longer in the document tree?

Comment: Yeah. That's essentially my problem. Elements are gone (good old web dev inspection shows that) but the nodelist acts as though they're still present. If I can find a good place to set up a sample of the code I will :)

Comment: My current attack plan is to test the .offsetParent to see if it returns null.